# Office 365 EWS does not return X-BackendOverrideCookie

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, affinity

Office 365 does not return the X-BackendOverrideCookie in response headers.

I set the X-AnchorMailbox and X-PreferServerAffinity in the request headers properly. This does not trigger X-BackendOverrideCookie to be returned, as it says in MSDN. Why is this happening?

Meanwhile, I tried the same thing with an on-premise Exchange 2016. Here I don't even set the X-AnchorMailbox and X-PreferServerAffinity and I get back the X-BackendOverrideCookie in each response. This is not good either, since I need to manage affinity for groups of pull and push notifications, and I need to set this cookie when I want, and not have it set always by default.

**Edit 1:**

The flow goes like this. I am sending the subscribe request using JS. For that purpose I use [lather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lather) to wrap my request into SOAP format.

This is how that operation looks like:

```
var impersonate = ‘myroomresource@mydomain.com’

var subscribe = {
         "m:Subscribe": {
                    "m:PullSubscriptionRequest": {
                        "t:FolderIds": {
                            "t:DistinguishedFolderId": {
                                attributes: [{
                                    'Id': this.distinguishedFolderId
                                }]
                            }
                        },
                        "t:EventTypes": [{
                            "t:EventType": "CreatedEvent"
                        }, {
                            "t:EventType": "DeletedEvent"
                        }, {
                            "t:EventType": "ModifiedEvent"
                        }],
                        "t:Timeout": "10"
                    }
                }
  };


soapHeader = {
                “t:ExchangeImpersonation": {
                   "t:ConnectingSID": {
                       't:SmtpAddress': impersonate
                   }
                }
             }

lather.up({
                body : requestName,          
                headers : {
                    Authorization : lather.basicAuth(this.username, this.password),            
                    'X-AnchorMailbox': impersonate,
                    'X-PreferServerAffinity': true
                },
                additionalNamespaces : [
                    'xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"',
                    'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"',
                ],
                soapHeader : soapHeader,
                method : 'POST',
                url : ‘https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx',
            }, function(error, res, body) {
               // Process the response
            })
```

When this executes the request is formed and sent out. When I look at the raw request being sent out, I confirm that the headers are in place.

```
headers: 
{ Authorization: 'Basic c29m…’, (shortened just in case)
'X-AnchorMailbox': ‘myroomresource@mydomain.com', (fake mail)
'X-PreferServerAffinity': true,
'Content-Length': 971,
'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
host: 'outlook.office365.com' }
```

Then I get back the following response from Office.

The body of the response: (shortened Ids, just in case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="693" MinorBuildNumber="12" Version="V2016_10_10" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></s:Header><s:Body><m:SubscribeResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><m:ResponseMessages><m:SubscribeResponseMessage ResponseClass=“Success”><m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode><m:SubscriptionId>KQB2aTFwcjA…wucsA==</m:SubscriptionId><m:Watermark>AQAAAFQ+2wmbaZF…JAAAAAAA=</m:Watermark></m:SubscribeResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:SubscribeResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

The headers of the response are: (shortened Ids, cookie)

```
{ 'cache-control': 'private',
'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
server: 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5',
'request-id': ‘2881ab3…1ec461’,
'x-calculatedbetarget': 'VI1PR0501MB2096.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com',
'x-backendhttpstatus': '200',
'set-cookie': [ ‘exchangecookie=d8f8…1e8; expires=Sat, 28-Oct-2017 08:41:27 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly' ],
'x-ewshandler': 'Subscribe',
'x-aspnet-version': '4.0.30319',
'x-diaginfo': 'VI1PR0501MB2096',
'x-beserver': 'VI1PR0501MB2096',
'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET',
'x-feserver': 'VI1PR0901CA0093',
date: 'Fri, 28 Oct 2016 08:41:26 GMT' }
```

As you can see I only get the exchange cookie, and no X-BackendOverrideCookie. Any ideas on what is going on? Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit 2**:

I also tried this with EWSEditor. Set the two headers, and made a pull subscription request. I get the same result as here.

**Edit 3:**

Here is the full [request](https://ybin.me/p/e3612aacf29c9a26#3kereTTh4iEwtwlQ3Gi9yvhj5NMtKe6HJ7d78DxiLh4=)

Comment: This works correctly for me and other people so most likely its a problem with your code so you will need to post what your are using.

Comment: I am using ews-javascript-api which is a JS port of the managed api. But now I even tried sending a raw ews request, added the headers, and the response from office only contains the exchangecookie, no backend override cookie. This is as simple as it gets, I don't see what I could be doing wrong. Are there any Office settings for setting this backend override cookie?

Comment: No I would suggest you post the raw request your using (including headers), its hard for anybody to tell you what your doing incorrectly if you don't show how your doing it.

Comment: @GlenScales please see my edit.

Comment: @GlenScales Do you have an example of a working application that manages affinity?

Comment: https://ewsstreaming.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EWSStreamingNotificationSample/EWSStreamingNotificationSample/GroupInfo.cs would be one. I use in streaming notifications where its important where your grouping multiple users in a single connection (and it would be a big problem if it didn't work), If i try a pull sample I don't see that cookie returned do you actually need that for Pull subscriptions? (as I would think the AnchorMailbox would be enough to do the routing) the documentation doesn't really add much clarity as its all focuses on Streaming notifications. good question though

Comment: @eomeroff Hi I am facing the same issue with Pull Subscriptions. Were you able to resolve the issue.  When I try the following  i) Create Pull Subscription with a previous watermark and ii) Call GetEvents i get two different responses for different runs. One with two events which is expected and another with empty events.  I thought it was due to 'affinity'.  But when I try to maintain affinity, i am not getting the 'X-BackendOverrideCookie' cookie

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't include the SOAP headers, but if you're encountering the same problems I was, then the issue is with the RequestServerVersion parameter in those headers.

Specifically, you'll want to include something like:

```
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1"/>
</soap:Header>
```

The important part is the Exchange2013_SP1. Without the _SP1, Office365 doesn't include the 'X-BackendOverrideCookie' cookie in the response.